# Transactional transfer messages between kafka clusters with spring

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have two kafka clusters. I need to implement kind of synchronization between them using kafka-spring.

```
[cluster A, topic A]  <-- [spring app] --> [cluster B, topic B]
```

I created listener annotated as @Transactional which posts messages with kafkaTemplate. This works perfectly when there is connection to both clusters. When connection to target cluster is lost - it seems that listener still acknowledge new messages, but they are not posted. I tried manual hacks on listener, disable auto commit, etc but they do not seem to work as I think they should.. When connection is back online the messages never get delivered. Need help with this.

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "A", containerFactory = "syncLocalListenerFactory")
    public void consumeLocal(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, @Payload SyncEvent message, Acknowledgment ack) {
        kafkaSyncRemoteTemplate.send("B", key, message);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

I am getting logs:

```
2019-04-26 12:11:40.808  WARN 21304 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-04-26 12:11:40.828  WARN 21304 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=app-sync] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-04-26 12:11:47.829 ERROR 21304 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='...' and payload='...' to topic B:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for sync-2: 30002 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

2019-04-26 12:11:47.829 ERROR 21304 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='...' and payload='...' to topic B:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for sync-2: 30002 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

--- edit ---

kafkaProperties here are default kafka-spring properties read from application.properties file, but in this case they are all default

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SyncEvent> syncLocalConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getStreams().getApplicationId() + "-sync");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        config.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, SyncEvent.class);
        config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "app.structures");

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, SyncEvent> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
        cf.setValueDeserializer(new JsonDeserializer<>(SyncEvent.class, objectMapper));
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "syncLocalListenerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SyncEvent> kafkaSyncLocalListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SyncEvent> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(syncLocalConsumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(0));
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: Kafka has a builtin tool called MirrorMaker to do this

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, but I do not want additional apps running (and I would need two for both ways). I want to do the same but integrated with my larger app. I am trying to do reverse engineering but it is not easy as MirrorMaker is in scala and written without any spring-like features, just plain kafka :(

Answer (score 0):

[This website](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-handling-message-conversion-transaction-support) describes how to set an Error handler (using a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`), it might help you out. From the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.html):

> SeekToCurrentErrorHandler: An error handler that seeks to the current offset for each topic in
>   the remaining records. Used to rewind partitions after a message
>   failure so that it can be replayed.

Comment: it did not change anything. It seems that kafkaTemplate.send() returns without error but just queues messege for delivery in memory and then expires it after some time. How to change that behavior?

Comment: Your snippet mentions the use of a `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean named "syncLocalListenerFactory". Could you post a code snippet of that bean? It might help us in viewing how you've defined the retryhandler and errorhandler.

Comment: figured out that kafkaTemplate return Future, so I added call .get() which should wait for result and throw RuntimeException on failure and Acknowlege::ack() on success but still same...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because kafka transactions cannot span across clusters. your @Transactional annotation has no meaning, so the offset is commited to cluster A regardless if publishing to cluster B succeeded or not.

The best guarantee you can currently achieve for cross-clusters stream is 'Atleast-once' processing, and you can reach it by making sure that the offset is committed to cluster A only after the destination broker from cluster B acknowledged the message.

For more info see my blog post on this exactly - https://medium.com/@harelopler/kafka-cross-cluster-stream-reaching-at-least-once-semantics-c74ed0eb1a54

Comment: Have you ever tried this technique in production?

Comment: Yes, more or less like in the blog post